# VMware workstation (v16.1.1) Nat Network. 2 out of 4 guest machines unable to ping other guest machines

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

VMWare Workstation 16.1.1 on Windows 10 Professional host.
Created 4 guest machines, each a trial version of Windows Server 2016 standard edition.

On 2 of the machines I was unable to ping the other 3 machines.
I could ping google.com from the 2 problem machines.

Using static IP addresses 192.168.64.151 to 154
Problem machines IP address .151 and .154
Added hostname entries to each of guest machines in windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file

The Windows firewall was enabled by default on the 4 guest machines.

Restarting the guest machines did not fix the problem.

Comment: If you wish a static IP address for your virtual machines, use Bridged Networking, not NAT.  This is reassigned in the VM settings.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the firewall on the 2 problem guest machines fixed the problem/ provided a work around